# Configure Apache between HAProxy and Tomcat servers

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, haproxy

[HAProxy architecture image (Please refer this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjcrB.jpg) I want to configure HAProxy with Apache and Tomcat Servers. My current application structure is Apache -> Tomcat. I need to configure HAProxy above Apache which is HAProxy -> Apache -> Tomcat. I am configuring HAProxy above Apache to add load balancing using multiple load balancers.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.